# Integrating Newton's second law for a box under the effect of return force from a spring and friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring

Let us imagine a box with mass $m$ connected to a spring with stiffness constant $k$. The box is displaced a distance $-d$ ($d$ being positive) from the origin. We want to find the maximum displacement reached from the origin by the box after a half period of oscillation of the spring. In other words, after I let go the box and the spring pulls it on the other side of its equilibrium point, how far from the equilibrium point (origin of the frame of reference) does the box end up, taking also into account kinetic friction? Kinetic friction is defined as $F_{fr} = \mu_kmg$

Edit: By plugging $m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx - \mu_kmg$  into WolframAlpha, one gets as a solution:

$x(t) = -\frac{\mu_kmg}{k} + c_1\cos(wt) + c_2\sin(wt)$

where $w = \sqrt\frac{k}{m}$ and $x_0 = -\frac{\mu_kmg}{k}$ is the particular solution.

However, it seems the solution can be rewritten as

$x(t) = x_0 + A\cos(wt)$,

where $A = -(x_0 + d)$.

How come the solution can be rewritten this way?

Comment: there is a lot missing in this question, length of spring? "kinetic friction"? $r*v,  or r*v^2..  r*mg?$ maybe you get it clearer for yourself and post what you did up to now,

Comment: @trula thanks for the suggestions! I added in more details and posted my progress up to now. Not sure whether the spring length counts?

Comment: Is the box on a level surface?  And a hint: conservation of energy is the easy way to work this problem.

Comment: You have to decide on $c_1,c_2$ by the initial condition .

Comment: Keep in mind that $A\sin\theta + B\cos\theta$ is equal to a single sine/cosine with shifted phase.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really about physics itself; it is about simplifying/rewriting a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
Initial conditions needed to be taken into account. After taking those into account ($x(0) = A = -(x_0 + d)$  and $v(0) = 0$) the equation of motion turns out to be exactly $x(t) = x_0 + A \cos(wt)$, with $ A = -(x_0 + d)$